# Custom directive to change input type attribute value

Tags: html, css, angularjs

For a field in my web page need to display numpd on the device for ainput field with type="password".
Tried doing this with CSS

```
<input type="tel" ....>
```

css:

```
#Id {
    -webkit-text-security : disc;
}
```

This works fine in iphone and android but not working in windows phone. Was even able to reproduce the issue in IE9.

Also tried adding a custom directive to do the same

```
myDirectives.directive('myIgnoreType', function() {
return {
    priority: 500,
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$set('type', 'password', false);
    }
}
});
```

but this also doesn't work.
Any idea how I can do this either with angular js or html

Comment: -webkit targets webkit browsers, IE isn't a webkit browser, so it won't target IE, or -moz (mozilla, firefox)

Comment: how do we target IE then?

Comment: You can't, really. this may be of interest though: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/12-password.html Although I think you might have to do some trickery to get the numpad. Such as having an invisible input field that's focused when they focus this password field, their input is hidden, in the invisible field, which is being populated by the numpad as it's type is "tel", then transfer the value over character by character on keyup? or something...

Comment: am not sure if that will be an optimum solution, though will do something like that in case don't find any other solution.
thanks

Comment: Can we not achieve this using angular js?